# Change page content with AJAX, then execute JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello so I have the following code:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","data.html",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And my button:

```
<a href="#" id="change-btn" onclick="loadXMLDoc(); return true;">Change page</a>
```

And my other script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#change-btn").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#page-changed").offset().top
        }, 2000, "swing", function(){
            $("#page-changed").effect('shake', {times: 1, direction: 'left', distance: 5}, 300);
        });
});
```

This works well if `#page-changed` is on top of the `data.html` file. But if it's at the bottom jQuery returns error that `offset.top is undefined` I understand that the problem is that jQuery can't find the `#page-changed` element in time and returns `undefined`. How to fix this?

Comment: If you are using jQuery anyway, why not use jQuery.ajax() instead of XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is performed asynchronously (as its name suggests), so you should wait for the AJAX call to be completed **before** changing the scroll position of the page. Also, since you are already using jQuery, then you can reduce your code for the AJAX call to using `$.ajax()` (or `$.get()`, which is a shorthand for GET requests), which is a lot simpler, and natively returned promises (which we listen on to check if AJAX call is complete).

Given your HTML, we remove the inline JS:

```
<a href="#" id="change-btn">Change page</a>
```

For your JS, that is quite simple—although you will need to fill in the details for the AJAX call yourself:

```
$('#change-btn').click(function(e) {

    // Prevent default
    e.preventDefault();

    // Make a GET request for data.html
    var loadXMLDoc = $.get({
        'url': 'data.html'
    });

    // Perform things when AJAX call is successful
    loadXMLDoc.done(function(data) {
        // Set innerHTML of #text element
        $('#text').html(data);

        // Then set scroll position
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#page-changed").offset().top
        }, 2000, "swing", function(){
            $("#page-changed").effect('shake', {
                times: 1,
                direction: 'left',
                distance: 5
            }, 300);
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: That is the beauty of jQuery - write less and do more! You could even get it shorter like: `$.get({'url':'data.html'}).done({function(data){ $('#text').html(data) ... });` - essentially a one-liner ;-)

Comment: @cars10 I chose not to chain, only because it might confuse new users :)

Comment: @Terry: very true - I like it anyway!!

Comment: @Charlie Well what messages do you see in your console log?

Comment: That's because `#page-changed` cannot be found. Are you sure it is loaded into the document? What is the data returned from your AJAX call?

Comment: Whoops excuse me, excuse me I haven't drank my coffee today... My bad I miss wrote data.html.